# Setup sharepoint to stream videos (10gig worth) for intranet and external access

Tags: 2010

I need to offer our teachers the ability to view avi's/wmv's relevant to their department and wondered if I could setup a media server to do this.  Then I wanted to create a list or something to point to these videos so teachers can view the videos internally in the school or externally (students too would be useful).

We run windows server 2008 and have set up a publishing point and linked to one video for testing purposes which works internally, but only on windows media player and NOT outside of the network.

What do i need to do to allow our staff/students access to play these on their choice of media players.  If its an issue we will have to force them down the microsoft route, but be nice since we provide tablets to staff and students.

Andy

Answer (score 2):

Even with Blob caching enabled, SharePoint is not well suited to streaming media for anything other than a very small group.  A better approach would be to set up your own [Media Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448620.aspx), put the content there and then simply link to it in SharePoint.  You can even embed the videos on pages in SharePoint.

As to the players themselves, well, there you will have to do some digging.  SharePoint offers a Silverlight player though odds are extremely good that most users will not have Silverlight installed.  Beyond that, there are a number of players available (like [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)) that could be used.  If you have someone available with a minimum of Flash experience, they can even create a video player pretty quickly though HTML5 would be the preferred option as Flash is not supported on Apple devices.

Comment: Don't forget IIS Media Services for streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing the videos in Azure and using the CDN's available there?

This will benefit storage of large files (so they are not in your content database) they are / can be globally available outside your core network and are streamed / delivered from the most local source.

I am also pretty sure that you can convert video files to other formats within Azure now although I've never tried it myself.

You could even code a BCS connection to query the video files, or use search to navigate them, or store links to them in a SharePoint list so you can also index metadata.

I have spent the last 2 years wanting and never getting round to a custom list where you can upload a video which then gets moved by an event handler to azure and replaced with a link.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

We're using a media server and then either use Media Web Parts, or a custom list to expose the video via a hyperlink.

There was actually a great article posted by Bil Simser recently discussing this: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2013/03/04/asp-net-training-videos-delivered-via-sharepoint.aspx